# Unofficial migrate Nexus 2 -> 3 possible for Maven artifacts?

Tags: maven, nexus, nexus3

First, I know that the upcoming Nexus 3.1 will offer migration of v2 to v3.
I also just applied for the beta migration for v2 to v3 (google forms).

My timing sucks, since the next few days I am going to setup and integrate a new Nexus 3 server.

*Is it possible to manually copy my old Maven artifacts (from Nexus v2 server) to this new Nexus v3 server and let Nexus v3 reindex everything? 
If so, how?*

Comment: The problem is that you need to upload them to the new Nexus 3 cause Nexus 3 uses a content repository instead of the plain file system on the hard drive...but writing some scripts to make an upload via rest might be a way to go..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to manually copy, however Nexus Repository Manager 3.1 is now released and you can use it to Upgrade.

As well, the incredible, edible Manfred Moser created this: https://github.com/simpligility/maven-repository-tools/tree/master/maven-repository-provisioner which you can use to take something from a file system into a Maven Repository AKA Nexus Repository Manager. I haven't used it myself, but it's probably exactly what you are looking for.

For those still checking this out, you can also use this simple bash script to import artifacts into Nexus Repository 3: https://gist.github.com/DarthHater/a4f2738e3bd40d242db22633b59dfd63

Comment: i am newbie in this area...can you please explain how can i proceed...my goal is also similar i have old nexus 2,5 and i want to copy all the artifact from this old nexus to new Nexus 3,58

Comment: @SachinMSharma, can you please tell me how did you get it to work? I have a Nexus 2.11 that I want to copy to Nexus 3.